# Install nbextensions in aws emr notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I am able to spin up a cluster and access jupyter notebooks. However, I do not see the nbextensions tab. I sshed into the master node and installed jupyter_contrib_nbextensions,
`pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`, but this did not help.

How can I get nbextensions to show up in my emr notebooks?

Thanks!